# Setting app:layout_behavior programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a coordinator layout with a recyclerview which I would like to add programmatically. The reason why it's added programatically is because different fragments which inflate the coordinator layout, may use different types of recyclerviews.

Typically for a recyclerview, in order to set this behaviour I would add it in the xml:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

That works fine. However, I'm at a complete loss as to how to add this behavior when I create the recyclerviews programmatically and then add them to the framelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

#### Explanation

`Behavior` is a parameter of the `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`. You can set the behavior on an instance of `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` with [`setBehavior`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html#setBehavior(android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior)) method.

To get a proper `Behavior` object that represents the same thing as `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` you should create an instance of [`AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html).

---

#### Example

(*this is a cleaned up version of my previous edits to the original answer*)

First you will have to get an instance of a **child** `View` of your `CoordinatorLayout`.
Let me get this clear: it is **NOT** the `CoordinatorLayout` itself. `childView` is `CoordinatorLayout's` child.

```kotlin
//e.g. like this:
val childView: View = findViewById(R.id.child_view)
```

Assuming the `childView` is already attached to the `CoordinatorLayout` (so it already has `LayoutParams`), you can do:

```kotlin
val params: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = yourView.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
params.behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
yourView.requestLayout()
```

Comment: Do you have an example where this is done programmatically?

Comment: `setBehavior` is causing an xml parse error when loading my fragment .. it is not working. In the case of fragments with their own class and xml, how do we do it? I notice in the docs there is an undocumented `public AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

Comment: That same behavior can be applied to LinearLayouts but I haven't been able to add it programmatically to yet. Do you happen to know how? I asked a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530196/how-to-add-and-remove-layout-behavior-programmatically-to-linearlayout

Comment: @BartekLipinski Can `yourView` be a `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Mark13426 I didn't say anything about `RecyclerView` but I assume you're asking if `ListView` can also work with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The answer is no. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` expects you to use a `View` that is implementing `NestedScrollingChild` interface. You could implement it yourself (for the `ListView`) but it seems like a pain in the butt in comparison to reimplementing your screen with `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: what if I use GridView inside some other ViewGroup? I mean the scrolling view is not directly the child of CoordinatorLayout, and they are all created programatically. Is there any way to set the layout behaviou? to which?

Comment: @tainy You can only set `behavior` for direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @BartekLipinski that is too bad. Is there any way that I can use AppBarLayout in my situation? In fact what I need is just move the title bar out of screen

Comment: @tainy it's not like some nasty feature of `CoordinatorLayout`. That's how whole Android SDK works. You can only set layout-specific parameters for direct children of a particular layout. I'd suggest you rethink your layout.

Comment: @BartekLipinski yes I agree that. The problem is the current layout. The existing layout is working for long time and is not intent to be changed in near period

Comment: I want to set the behavior for a view that I'm adding to the Coordinator Layout dynamically. So I'm calling mCoordinatorLayout.addView(customView) and I want to set the behavior of the custom view. However, the custom view doesn't seem to think that its layout params are CoordinatorLayout.Params

Comment: @fobbymaster paste that as a question, not as a comment to this answer

Answer (score 10):

To enable and disable `layout_behavior` programatically with **kotlin** use this code :

```
fun enableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val param: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = swipeRefreshView.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    param.behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
}

fun disableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val param: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = swipeRefreshView.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    param.behavior = null
}
```

Note: replace swipeRefreshView with your view

Comment: As soon as we disable layout behaviour, will the hidden bottom navigation view appear back automatically ?

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer is correct but the provided code is not compilable. So here is a complete example

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) 
view.getLayoutParams();

params.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior(view.getContext(), null));
```

2nd param is `AttributeSet` and it is fine to have it as `null` although it is not marked as `Nullable` in support lib.

Comment: why the code from my answer is not compilable? It seems to be compiling just fine for me?