# How to add and remove layout behavior programmatically to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

You can add the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` behavior to a `LinearLayout` in the XML declaration but I haven't found a way to do the same in code. With a `CoordinatorLayout` you can call `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.setBehavior()` but this method isn't available on `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Is there a way to do something similar for `LinearLayout`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33707476/5038993

Comment: @Akeshwar that doesn't work on `LinearLayout` because its `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` can't be cast to `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`. In fact I have a comment under that same answer stating that fact.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding `LayoutParams` concept a bit.

`LayoutParams` object is related to the enclosing `ViewGroup`, **not** to the modified `ViewGroup` itself.

Comment: That's probably true but on CoordinatorLayout it can be done so I'm wondering if there is a way to do it on LinearLayout too.

Comment: What exactly "can be done" on `CoordinatorLayout`? Take a good look a the question you posted your original comment. I do not do anything **on** the `CoordinatorLayout` itself. I do something on **it's child `View`**

Comment: Not in CoordinatorLayout itself but when you have a view inside of it. What I meant was that when you had a view inside one you could add and remove LayoutParams programmatically. Not that you did that on CoordinatorLayout directly.